# Getting the "com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to parse detail: START_TAG seen" while connecting Salesforce instance from Java code

Tags: soap-api, error

Getting the below exception while connecting Salesforce instance from Java code. I am using Partner WSDL now. But still getting the same exception.

```
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to parse detail:  START_TAG seen ...</sf:exceptionMessage><sf:upgradeURL>... @1:752 due to: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...</sf:exceptionMessage><sf:upgradeURL>... @1:752
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.parseDetail(SoapConnection.java:233)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.createException(SoapConnection.java:202)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:148)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:110)
    at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.login(PartnerConnection.java:1426)
    at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.<init>(PartnerConnection.java:406)
    at com.netapp.sfdc.sandbox.objects.CreatePartnerContact.login(CreatePartnerContact.java:76)
    at com.netapp.sfdc.sandbox.objects.CreatePartnerContact.main(CreatePartnerContact.java:25)
```

I am running the below code:

```
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig(); 
config.setUsername(username); 
config.setPassword(password); 
config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint); 
config.setTraceFile("traceLogs.txt"); 
config.setTraceMessage(true); 
config.setPrettyPrintXml(true); 
partnerConnection = new PartnerConnection(config);
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the request xml you are submitting, or the reply you get back?

Comment: I am just trying to login to salesforce env through Partner WSDL from the java code.

Comment: We won't be able to help you without seeing the xml used in the request and response. You need to [edit] your question to include this, as well as the code you are using to generate and handle the response/request.

Comment: I am running the below code: ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
           config.setUsername(username);
           config.setPassword(password);
          
           config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);
           config.setTraceFile("traceLogs.txt");
           config.setTraceMessage(true);
           config.setPrettyPrintXml(true);
           
           partnerConnection = new PartnerConnection(config);

Answer (score 8):

I have two suggestions.
Firstly, see if anything useful has been written to your trace file "traceLogs.txt" as this should contain the full response.
Secondly, be aware that Java 7 and lower does not use TLS1.1 or higher by default, so if you're not using Java 8, you'll need to add a JVM parameter of
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

Without the JVM parameters, I got exactly the same symptoms.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was using a jar for API version 37 with a partner URL with "38" in it. After changing the 38 in the partner URL to 37 it started working.

The exception looked like this when I called getUserInfo on PartnerConnection:
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...... @1:630

Answer (score 1):

This kind of Exception found when The **Login Credentials are invalid**.

Either the Connection URL / Username / Password -- Anyone of this might wrong.

Please check the below link which have discussion on same type of issue:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AXj1IAG

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved by navigating to Critical Updates -> deactivate Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections.

Comment: But if you dont want to disable the setting then try the "Andy Mitchell" answer. Just add -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 to the VM arguments section in eclipse.