# com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException with JDK 1.6.0_45

Tags: api, webservices, java

I am using Salesforce API version 39 to generate partner jar using wsc-22.jar

My project is deployed on JDK1.6.0_45, so i also wanted make my salesforce code compatible to JDK 1.6.

I run some sample login code to test LOGIN on salesforce setup, **It is working perfectly fine with** **JDK 1.8** but giving following exception when i run on **JDK 1.6**

```
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to parse detail:  START_TAG seen ...</sf:exceptionMessage><sf:upgradeURL>... @1:752 due to: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...</sf:exceptionMessage><sf:upgradeURL>... @1:752
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.parseDetail(SoapConnection.java:237)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.createException(SoapConnection.java:203)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:149)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:98)
    at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.login(PartnerConnection.java:1)
    at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.<init>(PartnerConnection.java:1)
    at com.sforce.soap.partner.Connector.newConnection(Connector.java:1)
```

I have also seen [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/140574/42717) asked on this community but it does not help me.

Sample code:

```
import com.sforce.soap.partner.Connector;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.GetUserInfoResult;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
           String username = "";
           String password = "";
           String authEndPoint = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39";

           try {
              ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
              config.setUsername(username);
              config.setPassword(password);        

              System.out.println("AuthEndPoint: " + authEndPoint);
              config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);

              PartnerConnection connection =Connector.newConnection(config);

              // Print user and session info
              GetUserInfoResult userInfo = connection.getUserInfo();
              System.out.println("UserID: " + userInfo.getUserId());
              System.out.println("User Full Name: " + userInfo.getUserFullName());
              System.out.println("User Email: " + userInfo.getUserEmail());
              System.out.println();
              System.out.println("SessionID: " + config.getSessionId());
              System.out.println("Auth End Point: " + config.getAuthEndpoint());
              System.out
                    .println("Service End Point: " + config.getServiceEndpoint());
              System.out.println();

           } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
              ce.printStackTrace();
           }
    }

}
```

Comment: Rings a bell on [TLS1.1 issue](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1&language=en_US). Have you tried adding the JVM parameter of -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 ?

Comment: yup, I have tried this already but still giving same problem.

Comment: Actually when i tried to set that property it gives, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TLSv1.1. And in jdk 1.6 they have given support of TLSv1.1 in Update 111. But it is not publically available. :-(